# scala anonymous function missing parameter type error

Tags: scala

I wrote the following

```
def mapFun[T, U](xs: List[T], f: T => U): List[U] = (xs foldRight List[U]())( f(_)::_ )
```

and when I did

```
def f(x: Int):Int=x*x
mapFun(List(1,2,3), f)
```

It worked fine. However, I really wanted to make the following work too

```
mapFun(List(1,2,3), x=>x*x)
```

It complains about "missing parameter type". I know that I could use currying, but is there any way to still use anonymous function for non-currying def I had above?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It seems to me that because "f" is in the same parameter list as "xs", you're required to give some information regarding the type of x so that the compiler can solve it.

In your case, this will work:

```
mapFun(List(1,2,3) , (x: Int) => x * x)
```

Do you see how I'm informing the compiler that x is an Int?

A "trick" that you can do is currying f. If you don't know what currying is check this out: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala

You will end up with a mapFun like this:

```
def mapFun[T, U](xs: List[T])(f: T => U): List[U] = 
    (xs foldRight List[U]())( f(_)::_ )
```

And this will work:

```
mapFun(List(1,2,3))(x => x * x)
```

In the last call, the type of x is resolved when the compiler checks the first parameter list.

**EDIT:**

As Dominic pointed out, you could tell the compiler what your types are. Leading to:

```
mapFun[Int, Int](List(1,2,3), x => x * x)
```

Cheers!

Comment: You can also specify the type params like so: `mapFun[Int, Int](List(1,2,3), x => x * x)`

Comment: Oh yeah, of course. You could always tell explicitly what your types are. Thanks Dominic.

Comment: I tried implementing his function on the List type using the Pimp my library pattern, but couldn't get the types to work. Possible?

Answer (score 18):

The limitation of scala's type system that you're running into here is that the type information flows from left to right **across parameter groups** and does not flow from left to right **within a parameter group**.

What this means is that specifying the type parameter `T` by providing a `List[Int]` will not provide that information to other parameters within the group like `f`. Which results in a missing parameter type error. But it will provide it to `f` if f were a part of the next parameter group. This is why the curried function approach works.

i.e. if you defined it like this:

```
def mapFun[T, U](xs: List[T])(f: T => U): List[U] = (xs foldRight List[U]())( f(_)::_ )
```

The type parameter `T` that you define in the first parameter group: `(xs: List[T])` as `Int` will be made available to the next parameter group: `(f: T => U)`. So now you do not have to explicitly specify `T` at the call site.

Comment: Would be awesome to learn more about this limitation, is there anything written about it in the spec?