# Scala - missing parameter type - is it possible to avoid assisting the compiler?

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism

This works, but I would like to avoid assisting the compiler as I have no idea what the tag type should be, I just know it will be of type Field.

```
val x: TypeString = TypeString("test")

TypeValidator.validate[TypeString](x, x => {
  true
})
```

What I would ideally like to have is: (where x type is inferred)

```
TypeValidator.validate(x, x => {
  true
})
```

The validation class is as follows

```
import models.implementations.Field

object TypeValidator {
  def apply(): TypeValidator = {
    new TypeValidator()
  }
  def validate[T <: Field](t: T, v: T => Boolean): Boolean = {
    new TypeValidator().validate(t, v)
  }
}

class TypeValidator {
  def validate[T <: Field](t: T, v: T => Boolean): Boolean = v.apply(t)
}
```

Having searched around on here for about an hour, I've come to the conclusion I might not be able to avoid this, but I would still like to hope someone has a solution.

Perhaps the closest I've come to finding an answer was here:

[scala anonymous function missing parameter type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115053/scala-anonymous-function-missing-parameter-type-error)

**Update** - just to add, this does work, but I feel there might be a better solution still:

```
TypeValidator.validate(x)(x => {
  true
})
```

Changed the class to ad a second set of parameters for the anonymous function.

```
class TypeValidator {
  def validate[T <: Field](t: T)(v: T => Boolean): Boolean = v.apply(t)
}
```

Comment: What don't you like about the last solution?

Comment: You can remove curly braces from your second solution and replace parenthesis with curly. Less typing and it is *the* solution in my opinion. Currying is quite common thing to do to help type inference. For example `foldLeft` on list uses this.

Comment: @MichaelZajac, this just feels more of a hack than anything else. While the solution works, it just seems overly complex too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no better solution than

```
class TypeValidator {
  def validate[T <: Field](t: T)(v: T => Boolean): Boolean = v.apply(t)
}
```

Any other solution will needlessly complicate the signature of `validate`.

Scala's type inferencer goes through parameter lists one by one, so when it saw the old version, it tried to infer `T` from both the function argument and the `Field` argument, and failed because the type of the function argument was no fully known. Here, the inferencer takes the `Field` argument without thinking about the function argument, and infers that `T = TypeString`. This allows it to then infer the function argument's argument's type.

You will find that this is a very common pattern throughout the Scala standard library and basically all other Scala libraries.

Further, you can and should omit the parentheses around the function argument:

```
TypeValidator.validate(x) { x =>
  true
}
```